# How to clean the previous title text on back button in navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Normally, the back button of UINavigationbar will show a back arrow, follow by the previous page title, so how to only show the back arrow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that you have two viewcontrollers `vc1->vc2`

In **vc1**,in viewDidLoad

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

Screenshot

[image]